# Which file should I compile from source code folder in VB

Tags: vb6

I have a source code folder of a software and it is written in VB 6.0.

The source code folder contains different files. Which file should I open and compile?

May you please tell me step by step procedure of opening a file with help of VB 6.0.

Comment: What are you tried by yourself?

Comment: @Rizwan - For what are you trying to open and compile this file , I mean what is your end goal? Do you just want to run this application? It is very unclear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you open VB6 the **New Project** window opens by default. Click the **Existing** tab and browse to your source code folder. The **Files of type** file filter will already be set to the default VB6 project file types.

*.mak - Older VB projects. I'm not sure when this was changed, but VB3 still used this extension.
*.vbp - The default VB6 project file extension
*.vbg - The default extension for a group of projects

If you have a *.vbg file, you should have multiple *.vbp files and the *.vbg file is probably the file you want. Otherwise, unless you are opening a really old project you will probably open the *.vbp file. If you have multiple *.vbp files in your source code folder without a *.vbg file present open the *.vbp file with the name closest to the exe, or dll file you are trying to compile the code to, if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project file (.VBP) in the VB6 IDE. `File` menu, `Open Project`

Suggestion: read some VB6 tutorials...